# Assign value to tensor according to another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I tried to use tf.assign to assign value to my tensor according to another tensor which has boolean value. The code is

```
self.labels_gt = self.labels_gt[self.gt_single_mask == False].assign(-1)
```

What I try to do is simple, assign `-1` to `self.labels_gt` if the the corresponding index in `self.gt_single_mask` is `False`. But it throws an error

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'begin' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```